# C++ rvalue assignment what caused this program to crash but lvalue assignment not

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ rvalue reference by example. It was like this:

```
Intvec::~Intvec()
{
    log("destructor");
    if (m_data) {
        delete[] m_data;
        m_data = 0;
    }
}

Intvec::Intvec(const Intvec& other)
    :m_size(other.m_size), m_data(new int[m_size])
{
    log("copy constructor");
    for(size_t i = 0; i<m_size; ++i)
        m_data[i] = other.m_data[i];
}

Intvec& Intvec::operator=(const Intvec& other)
{
    log("copy assignment operator");
    Intvec tmp(other);
    std::swap(m_size, tmp.m_size);
    std::swap(m_data, tmp.m_data);
    return *this;
}
```

Then I changed it to be following. When debugging step by step, it calls `delete[]` many times until it crashes: `read access violation at: 0x3f7a2f91`

```
Intvec& Intvec::operator=(const Intvec& other)
{
    log("copy assignment operator");
    size_t othersize = other.m_size;
    int* otherdata = other.m_data;
    std::swap(m_size, othersize);
    std::swap(m_data, otherdata);
    return *this;
}
```

I am confused at:

1. In example, `Intvec tmp(other)` returns a tmporary tmp object, it would be destroyed after `return *this`, it does not crash.
2. In my code, `other` is an rvalue, it is also destroyed after `return *this`, why it crashes because of read access at wrong memory.

It only happens to rvalue, not lvalue.

```
    Intvec v1 = Intvec(10);
    Intvec v2;
    cout << "assigning lvalue...\n";
    v2 = v1;
    cout << "ended assigning lvalue...\n";

    Intvec v2;
    cout << "assigning rvalue...\n";
    v2 = Intvec(33);
    cout << "ended assigning rvalue...\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the same m_data pointer twice. The problem starts here:

```
Intvec& Intvec::operator=(const Intvec& other)
{
    log("copy assignment operator");
    size_t othersize = other.m_size;
    int* otherdata = other.m_data;
    std::swap(m_size, othersize);
    std::swap(m_data, otherdata);
    return *this;
}
```

Decide if you want to transfer ownership, or duplicate. If you want to transfer ownership, then you need to set other.m_data = NULL after swapping it so that the r-value temporary object doesn't delete its own m_data when it destructs. You also need to delete the original m_data in the destination object PRIOR to swapping if it's not NULL (Apparently it is not NULL because otherwise the swap function would set other.m_data to NULL for you and there would be no problem).

If instead you'd rather duplicate it, then you need to structure your assignment operator more similarly to your copy constructor.

Comment: I see, I swap a temporary `size_t` and `int*`, not the one in object `other`, so it is deleted twice. BTW, I just noticed why in example (the one does not crash), `swap` can work on `const reference`, it changes `other` object anyway?

Comment: Where in your code is `swap` acting on a `const` reference? `tmp` is a copy of `other`.

Comment: @NathanPierson you are right. Made the same mistake again.

Comment: Still, why in case of lvalue assignment, my code deletes the same memory `m_data` twice at the end of program (`v1` and `v2`), why it does not crash?

Comment: It [crashes for me](https://godbolt.org/z/crrWveK6G). Undefined behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

For your `operator=`, after `v2 = Intvec(33);`, the data member `m_data` of both `v2` and the temporary `Intvec` point to the same array allocated. Then with the destroy of the temporary and `v2`, `m_data` would be deleted twice, which leads to UB.